# Can I stop iPhone apps from changing my Gmail status?

Tags: gmail, iphone, google-voice

I recently got the [Mo+ GV iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-for-google-voice-talk/id541829441?mt=8%20%22MO%20) to replace talkatone and it's a thousand times better. The problem is is that when I'm logged in (It connects to GTalk/voice) my gmail status is changed to an annoying ad. something like "I'm using Mo+ get it now at blah blah", and I know a lot of other apps do this too. Is there a way to disable this from happening? (Its not in the app settings)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable Google Talk status changes by third party apps, so stop using Mo+ GV and start using Google's Google Voice app with something like Sipgate [(see this article)](http://lifehacker.com/5349506/make-free-voip-calls-from-google-voice). If an app doesn't let you stop its shameless self-promotion, stop using it.

Comment: Or, you know, pay for it. You want apps for free the dev's gotta pay the bills somehow.

Comment: doesn't even have an option to pay to disable it